# Cannot create DigitalOcean Droplet through docker-machine command

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I run this command to create a new droplet on DigitalOcean

```
docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token xxxxxxx --digitalocean-size 1gb docker-app-machine
```

But it's not successfully executed, this is the log:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(docker-app-machine) Creating SSH key...
(docker-app-machine) Creating Digital Ocean droplet...
(docker-app-machine) Waiting for IP address to be assigned to the Droplet...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err : exit status 1
output : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

However, the droplet is created, I can see it in the admin panel. Do you know what's going on?

Docker:
Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)
Channel: stable
d1db12684b

docker-machine version 0.10.0, build 76ed2a6

running on a mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Maybe a better question for SuperUser?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo`?

Comment: I tried sudo and I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a bug with the version 0.10.0 of docker-machine, you just have to upgrade docker-machine to the 0.12.1 version using this command(mac)

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.12.1/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Posible explanation of the bug:
[docker-machine create with digitalocean driver: ssh command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854819/docker-machine-create-with-digitalocean-driver-ssh-command-error)